# In dnd 5e, can the Charger feat's bonus damage crit?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, critical-hit

The wording in the feat's description is "gain a +5 to the attack's damage roll", while for crits we "roll all of the attack’s damage dice twice". This suggests to me that the bonus damage is doubled as well. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No

there is a strict difference between a 'die' and 'bonus' (like '+5'). As you quoted, the die (or dice) is (or are) rolled twice, and then you add the bonus.

See for example this rule:

> CRITICAL HITS (PHB)
> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice
> for the attack's damage against the target. Roll all of the
> attack's damage dice twice and add them together. Then
> add any relevant modifiers as normal.

Also, the feat Savage Attacker is similar to the Charger

> SAVAGE ATTACKER (PHB)
> Once per turn when you roll damage for a melee weapon
> attack, you can reroll the weapon's damage dice and use
> either total.

In the *Sage Advice Compendium* it says:

> **Does the benefit of the Savage Attacker feat apply to
> additional effects like the rogue’s Sneak Attack or the
> paladin’s Divine Smite?** No. The benefit of Savage Attacker
> applies only to rolls of the weapon’s damage dice,
> not to any extra damage that a feature or other ability
> might grant.